# How to turn off html loading before css

Tags: html, css

I downloaded one site template. And I noticed that it first loads the html, and then the css starts to load. How to disable it? I want to make a preloader

Comment: provide some code that so users can understand where the problem exists exactly.....

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

import the css inside the head tag
which will help to load the css first then HTML body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Create a preloader first in html and after your document is ready hide it through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say how to resolve your problem without seeing the code. 
**But you can place the html code of your pre-loader at the very beginning of the body and put its style in the head section of same page with the help of  tag.**